# Как вычислить сумму 1!+2!+3!+...+n!

Tags: python, python-3.x, ряды

Условие задачи:

> По данному натуральном n вычислите сумму
> 1!+2!+3!+...+n!. В решении этой задачи можно
> использовать только один цикл. Пользоваться математической библиотекой
> math в этой задаче запрещено.

```
n = int(input())
N = 1
sum = 0
for a in range(1, n+1):
    for b in range(1, a+1):
        N = N * b
    sum += N
print(sum)
```

Однако у меня решение не выходит.
Подскажите, как решить правильно?

Comment: Если циклами нельзя, то рекурсия в помощ

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Если на вход подаются только натуральные `n`, то можно так:

```
n = int(input())
sum_of_factorials = 1
curr_factorial = 1
for i in range(2, n + 1):
    curr_factorial *= i
    sum_of_factorials += curr_factorial
print(sum_of_factorials)
```

(Вам же нужно `1!+2!+3!+...+n!` ? Или вы не опечатались? Если нет, то `sum_of_factorials` просто на `2` домножить в конце и отнять `1`).

Это весьма простое динамическое программирование. Вам не нужно каждый раз заново вычислять `curr_factorial`, чтобы его прибавить, т.к. нынешний `curr_factorial` - это просто старое значение, домноженное на номер текущего цикла итерации.

Answer (score 8):

```
n = int(input())

suma = 0
previous = 1       # Предыдущий факториал

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    current = previous * i    # Текущий факториал - см. примечание после кода
    suma += current
    previous = current

print(suma)
```

Здесь используется факт, что факториал числа равен факториалу предыдущего числа умноженный на текущее число - например `5! == 4! * 5`, потому что

```
 5! == 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 == (1 * 2 * 3 * 4) * 5 == 4! * 5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
number = int(input())

spicok = list(range(1,number+1))

factorial_current=1

summa=0

for n in spicok:
    
    factorial_current = factorial_current*n
    summa += factorial_current
    
print(summa)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n = int(input())
s = 0
res = 1

for i in range (1, n+1):
   res *= i
   s = s + res

print(s)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Можно было решать, используя библиотеку math.

```
from math import factorial
n = int(input())
sum = 0
for i in range(1, n+1):
    sum += factorial(i)
print(sum)
```

Comment: Пользоваться математической библиотекой math в этой задаче запрещено. (цитата)

Comment: И этот способ слишком затратный по сравнению с рекурентной формулой

Comment: И называть свою переменную так же, как встроенная функция `sum` тоже не хорошо

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю начать с конца:

```
n = int(input())
s = 0
for i in range(n, 0, -1): s = (s+1) * i
print(s)
```

или

```
from functools import reduce
n = int(input())
print(reduce(lambda s, i: (s+1) * i, range(n, 0, -1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Эту задачу можно решить, используя вложенный цикл:

```
res1 = 1
res2 = 0
number = int(input('Введите число: '))
for i in range(1, number + 1):
    for j in range(1, i + 1):
        res1 *= j
    res2 += res1
    res1 = 1
print(res2)
```

Answer (score -1):

> Он был так близок !!!

```py
n = int(input("Введите факториал : "))
        
f=1
summ=0

for i in range(2, n+1):
    for j in range (1,i+1):
        f = f * j
    summ+=f 
         
print("Ваш факториал равен =",summ)
# (ввод - 5)(вывод - 34 560 )
```

Comment: Условия принципиально не читал?

Answer (score -1):

```
    numberN = int(input("Введите число N: "))
    while numberN < 0: # фильтр отриц. чисел
        numberN = int(input('Число N < 0. Введите N >= 0: '))
    factorial = 1
    total = 0
    
    for numbers in range(1, numberN + 1):
        factorial *= numbers
        total += factorial
    if total == 0: # исключение для N = 0
        total = 1
    print(total)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -3):

```
from math import factorial
print(f"{factorial(int(input()))}")
```

так не проще?

Comment: 1. `Пользоваться математической библиотекой math в этой задаче запрещено.` 2. Вы вычисляете просто факториал, а нужно сумму факториалов